# TYPO3: Performance in Extbase Model

Tags: php, performance, typo3, extbase

Let's assume I have a model with a property:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $myProperty;
```

There's no database field for this property, the data for this property is retrieved from somewhere else:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getMyProperty() {
    return getDataFromSomewhere();
}
```

The problem I see here is, if I use this property more than once, the function is called multiple times. And if this function retrieves the data e.g. from a different table with mysql joins or does some extensive calculation, this is inperformant.

What are my possibilities here? Enhance the getter a little bit?

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getMyProperty() {
    if($this->myProperty === NULL) {
        $this->setMyProperty(getDataFromSomewhere());
    }
    return $this->myProperty;
}
```

I know I could use a Caching Framework and cache the value returned by function "getDataFromSomewhere", but I'm looking for an easier solution.

Comment: totally different approach would be to do your fetching & calculations using a cronjob and writing the rendered value into your database column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the getter method do `return $this->myProperty ?? ($this->myProperty = getDataFromSomewhere());`. Then it fills the local property before returning the value if it is null - which you of course make sure the property gets initialised as.

Comment: This is just a shorter form of my getter method, right? I'm still preferring my getter, because I compare the property to NULL (0, -1, false and so on could be valid values for the property) and I think it is better to use the setter method.

Comment: The `??` operator is called null coalesce operator because it only triggers the "else" part if the variable is exactly null (not falsey, not empty, but null). It does what you need it to do without having to write an if-then statement. Keeps your getter method one-line only.

Comment: Regarding calling the setter method, in my opinion it is incorrect logic to have a getter method call a setter method. You're not actually setting the property, you're "thawing" it. Thus, internal operation that doesn't call methods.

Answer (score 1):

The second variant of the getter-method you propose is a good idea and in general known as "lazy loading". The field `myProperty` is only filled with data, when it is accessed. On the other hand, if the getter-method is never called, the data doesn't need to be loaded at all.

You may choose another coding style like using [the ternary-](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) or [null coalescing operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce), but the scheme is the same. You can [find more examples of your idea on the web](https://www.google.com/search?hl=all&q=php%20object%20member%20lazy%20loading%20getter).